# SQL to find the majority value across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
 id  | value1 | value2 | value3
-----+--------+--------+--------
 id1 | a      | a      | b
 id2 | a      | b      | c
 id3 | b      | b      | c
 id4 | c      | c      | c
```

I'd like to find the rows where a majority of the values match (ie. at least 2 of the values match), so for the data given above here's the output I'd like:

```
 id  | majority_value
-----+----------------
 id1 | a
 id3 | b
 id4 | c
```

Comment: If at all possible, I would change your database structure to store teh data properly in a related table. No table shoudl ever be deisgned this way except staging tables to allow you to pull indata from files and then transform the data to your real structure.  Production tables should never have this structure as it violates the first normal form.

Comment: @HLGEM: Do we have enough information for such a claim? `No table should ever be designed this way`. I'd say it may well be a perfectly valid design and this task emerged somehow.

Comment: @HLGEM the example table is simplified, but there are lots of ways in which a real and correctly designed table could follow this structure, and you'd want to find the majority value. For example, a user table that had a first, middle and last name column, and you'd like to find users that have one of those in common with the others. You wouldn't want to break those name fields out into a separate table.

Answer (score 3):

Date types of all value columns must match (or cast all to the same type).

#### Simple case

This should be fastest for the simple case of **exactly 3 value columns**, all of them **`NOT NULL`**. The `id` column does not have to be unique.

```
SELECT id, CASE value1 WHEN value2 THEN value2 ELSE value3 END AS val
FROM   tbl
WHERE  value1 = value2 OR value2 = value3 OR value1 = value3
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Doesn't work for NULL values. (Can easily be extended.)

#### General solution

For **any odd number of value columns** (define a tiebreaker for even number!).
The `id` column must be unique.

```
SELECT t.id, t1.val
FROM   tbl t
     , LATERAL (VALUES (value1), (value2), (value3)) t1(val) -- list all
GROUP  BY 1, 2
HAVING count(*) > 1  -- 1 being 3/2 (integer division)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/479c0/6) (test case extended with NULL values).

Even works for NULL values.

Similar to [your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612760/939860) and [@Giorgos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613411/939860)' ideas, but the `VALUES` expression is much more efficient. Details in this related answer:

- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102743/3684)

Comment: On the full dataset of 7,612,771 rows your general solution takes 443,444.854 ms, whereas my array/unnest solution (which I would assume to be less efficient) only takes 369,926.383 ms

Comment: @BenDowling: That's a surprising result. I have compared both solutions before [for the linked answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102743/3684) and the `VALUES` expression was the clear victor. Are you sure what you see is not the effect of populated cache on the second run? You would have to run a couple of time to exclude such effects. Also, what's the performance of the simple solution? Should be fastest. You can test with a smaller subset, so the test doesn't take as long.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this alternative and see how it compares to your solution:

```
SELECT id, t.x
FROM value_table
JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT value1 AS x UNION ALL 
   SELECT value2 UNION ALL 
   SELECT value3) t ON true
GROUP BY id, t.x
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c4b8a/13)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution that combines the different values into an array, and then unnests them and works out the count per id. Here's the query:

```
SELECT id, value AS majority_value FROM (
SELECT id, unnest(values) AS value, count(1) FROM (
    select *, array[value1, value2, value3] AS values from value_table
    ) a GROUP BY id, value
) b WHERE count > 1;
```

And here's the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for it:

```
                                                           QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=2509.60..2559.60 rows=20000 width=64) (actual time=0.079..0.082 rows=3 loops=1)
   Sort Key: b.id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=778.83..1080.83 rows=20000 width=64) (actual time=0.058..0.067 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=778.83..880.83 rows=20000 width=128) (actual time=0.056..0.059 rows=3 loops=1)
               Filter: (count(1) > 1)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 5
               ->  Seq Scan on value_table  (cost=0.00..268.83 rows=51000 width=128) (actual time=0.014..0.032 rows=12 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.127 ms
(9 rows)
```

I expect that a much more efficient query exists though.